# How to create a pointer to array of pointers pointing to nodes in c?

Tags: c, pointers

[Pointer to array of pointers pointing to nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRy8H.png)

I want to create a pointer to an array of pointers, and that pointer inside the array points to nodes.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to image 2D points nodes array as 1D vector. That will help you image this question.

If you want to set many groups nodes coordinate

Group 1: node1X,node1Y,node2X,node2Y,node3X,node3Y .........

Group 2: node1X,node1Y,node2X,node2Y,node3X,node3Y .........

Group 3: node1X,node1Y,node2X,node2Y,node3X,node3Y .........

.......

```
void main()
{
//5 groups,each group have 4 nodes
int ** groups=(int**) malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) groups[i] = (int*)malloc(4*2 * sizeof(int));
//set
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        groups[i][j * 2] = j;
        groups[i][j * 2 + 1] = j;
    }
}
//printf
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Group[%d]:", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        printf("node[%d]X=%d ", j, groups[i][j*2] );
        printf("node[%d]Y=%d ,", j, groups[i][j*2+1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) free( groups[i]);
free( groups);
system("pause");
}
```

Remember to delete memory!

[Print result sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2duq.jpg)

Comment: Please note that the question was changed to C only before you posted this answer. You need to either rewrite this answer in pure C or delete it, since it is currently off-topic.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for reminding.I corrected the answer.It should be pure C now.

Answer (score -2):

you mean `data_type **identifier`, you could n dimension in your array declaration.

`data_type **identifier = malloc(sizeof(data_type))`

then for example assigning the first element of this array could be.

`identifier[0] = malloc(size_of_this_array * sizeof(data_type))`

Comment: The first `malloc` should have `sizeof(*data_type)`

Comment: yeah, is a mistake.